# Making a panel in border layout to float over center panel

Tags: layout, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using border layout in ExtJs 4 wherein the east panel is a collapsible panel. When I expand the panel it forces the center panel to adjust (shrink). Similarly When the east panel is collapsed the center panel retracts.

The desired behavior is that when I expand the east panel it should float over the center panel and not force it to adjust itself. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `floatable: true` config option on the east panel. See also the [Border layout example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/layout/border.html).

Comment: I have tried the floatable property and it didn't work. It does not work in the example as well. If you set the text in the "Center" panel as center then you will notice that when you expand the "East" panel the text in the "Center" panel moves / adjusts accordingly. The "East" panel doesn't really float.

Comment: There is a difference between expanding/collapsing a panel, and floating it. Collapse one of the side panels first and then click on it - the panel will float-expand to show its contents without changing  the center region. This is what `floatable: true` does. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I get it now. Yes, the desired behavior is achieved by clicking the panel header. Ideally I would like to achieving the said behavior on the click of collapse button or better yet by changing the mouse icon to hover icon (palm with index finger opened) when mouse hovers over the panel header. For now thanks a lot, my query is answered.