# Removing ExtJs' panel's collapse button and it's floating animation

Tags: extjs, extjs4

While using ExtJs border layout I want my East panel to be expandable & collapsible only by clicking on the panel's header, i.e. use floating characteristic. My queries are:

- How do I remove the collapse button?
- How do I remove floating animation? (animCollapse property seems to
  work only on collapse & expand actions performed on the collapse
  button)

Answer (score 3):

```
Ext.require(['*']);

Ext.onReady(function() {

    new Ext.container.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [{
            region: 'west',
            collapsed: true,
            hideCollapseTool: true,
            floatable: true,
            width: 200,
            title: 'Foo'
        }, {
            region: 'center'
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: Ooops! The floatable property when set as false removes the capability to expanding altogether. I want just the animation to go away and not the act of expanding. Note that I have tried also tried animCollapse:false which works only if the collapse button is being use. BTW, thanks because hideCollapseTool:true does work as desired.

Comment: Updated answer, you also need `titleCollapse`.

Comment: This does not address my concern when I view my problem in totality. Can you please look at following to see where is all started?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576497/making-a-panel-in-border-layout-to-float-over-center-panel/18625410?noredirect=1#comment27422658_18625410

Comment: Thanks but sadly the animation still exists. I want the panel to open up immediately and not with animation effect.

Comment: +1ing cause I got what I was looking for... `floatable:false` suppresses the floating animation and hence a panel can be viewed only by clicking on the collapse/expand button.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to ExtJS 4.1.2 disabling the animation for floated panels was not possible.
Now, the animation will be disabled if animCollapse is set to 0.

**Important!!!**
The animCollapse property can be set to true, false, or the animation duration in milliseconds. However, if set to false it will still use the default animation time. It must be set to 0. I believe this is a bug and it's not yet fixed in 4.2.2

If you want to disable the animation but you are unable to update your project to ExtJS 4.1.2 or higher add the duration to the slideIn call in floatCollapsedPanel and to the slideOut call in slideOutFloatedPanel in the Ext.panel.Panel source code.

```
...
me.el.slideIn(slideDirection, {
    preserveScroll: true,
    duration: Ext.Number.from(me.animCollapse, Ext.fx.Anim.prototype.duration),
    listeners: {
        afteranimate: function() {
            me.isSliding = false;
        }
    }
});
...
```

and

```
...
compEl.slideOut(collapseDirection, {
    preserveScroll: true,
    duration: Ext.Number.from(me.animCollapse, Ext.fx.Anim.prototype.duration),
    listeners: {
        afteranimate: function() {
            me.slideOutFloatedPanelEnd();
            // this would be in slideOutFloatedPanelEnd except that the only other
            // caller removes this cls later
            me.el.removeCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'border-region-slide-in');
            me.isSliding = false;
        }
    }
});
...
```

See the 4.1.2 source code for Ext.panel.Panel: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.2/source/Panel5.html#Ext-panel-Panel